# How can I access environment variables in Python?

Tags: python, environment-variables

How can I get the value of an environment variable in Python?

Answer (score 4580, accepted):

Environment variables are accessed through [`os.environ`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.environ):

```
import os
print(os.environ['HOME'])
```

To see a list of all environment variables:

```
print(os.environ)
```

---

If a key is not present, attempting to access it will raise a `KeyError`. To avoid this:

```
# Returns `None` if the key doesn't exist
print(os.environ.get('KEY_THAT_MIGHT_EXIST'))

# Returns `default_value` if the key doesn't exist
print(os.environ.get('KEY_THAT_MIGHT_EXIST', default_value))

# Returns `default_value` if the key doesn't exist
print(os.getenv('KEY_THAT_MIGHT_EXIST', default_value))
```

Comment: os.environ is a dictionary. Trying to access a key not present in the dictionary will throw a KeyError. The get method simply returns None when the key does not exists. Do you have PYTHONPATH set? Can you try with a variable such as PATH, that is guaranteed to exist? Does it return a meaningful value?

Comment: I haven’t set it (PYTHONPATH) before; what I am doing just go with command prompt and type CMD anywhere (since python.exe is in my shell PATH). If I try to access Window ENVIRONMENT variable, it gives mapped value but the problem with Python ENVIRONMENT variable like; PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME.

Comment: PYTHONPATH is used to add new search path to Python (sys.path) from outside Python. Have a look at http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#environment-variables

Comment: Is there any way to keep this variable persistent ?? When I run python later on the environment variable is gone and gives a `raise KeyError(key)` instead

Comment: @mrid There is no direct way from python to persist the environment variable. On windows you can write them in the registry, on Linux/OSX you might have to change you environment using scripts.

Comment: is this a portable solution?

Comment: @CharlieParker Yes, as far as I know, it is portable.

Comment: `.get()` can also be given a default.

Comment: For checking whether a environmental variable is set to some value, try: 
`if getenv('your_variable') == 'your value':`

Comment: @Rod.  It's not entirely portable if python is embedded inside another application. It is based on the execution context, ie shell, kind of shell, etc. MacOS environment variables may not exist if launched by double-clicking outside the terminal. In UNIX everything is presumed to be a shell, whereas Windows doesn't care. So while it does retrieve environment variables, you can't depend on what it returns.

Comment: Or you can just handle the `KeyError` normally in an `try... except`, handling the case where this env variable under that key is not found. This is not a bad thing, but a common accepted idiomatic python thing to do to handle expected error cases this way. It also prevents outside state to be different between an `if` check and getting the actual value for example (preventing TOCTTOU issues, time of check to time of use).

Comment: Can also interpolate using string templates: 
```import os

home = f"HOME is {os.environ['HOME']}"
print(home)```

Answer (score 360):

To check if the key exists (returns `True` or `False`)

```
'HOME' in os.environ
```

You can also use `get()` when printing the key; useful if you want to use a default.

```
print(os.environ.get('HOME', '/home/username/'))
```

where `/home/username/` is the default

Comment: Which is better, `"HOME" in os.environ` or `os.environ.get('HOME')`?

Comment: @endolith They do different things. The first returns True or False, while the second returns a value, possibly None.

Comment: @endolith, the correct question woud be `"HOME" in os.environ` vs `os.environ.get('HOME') is None`. As you can see first is far more readable & comfortable to work with.

Answer (score 96):

Actually it can be done this way:

```
import os

for key, value in os.environ.items():
    print(f'{key}: {value}')
```

Or simply:

```
for key, value in os.environ.items():
    print('{}: {}'.format(key, value))
```

or:

```
for i, j in os.environ.items():
    print(i, j)
```

For viewing the value in the parameter:

```
print(os.environ['HOME'])
```

Or:

```
print(os.environ.get('HOME'))
```

To set the value:

```
os.environ['HOME'] = '/new/value'
```

Comment: No, this answer really doesn't add anything on top of the existing answers

Comment: This should be removed, it is a duplicate of other answers. `str.format` is just a fancy addition.

Comment: The first answer with readable output for the entire env, thanks. To view the env in the PyCharm debugger, I evaluate `{k: v for k,v in sorted(os.environ.items())}`

Comment: it adds how to set the value

Answer (score 80):

Here's how to check if `$FOO` is set:

```
try:  
   os.environ["FOO"]
except KeyError: 
   print "Please set the environment variable FOO"
   sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Try can be faster. The case of env vars is likely best for 'try':
http://stackoverflow.com/a/1835844/187769

Comment: @RandomInsano faster =/= better. This code looks less readable than an `"if 'FOO' not in os.environ: ..."` block

Comment: If you just setup the variable you need to close the Terminal before you can test it.

Comment: Could the environment variable change (from another thread or from an outside source) between the if check and the access? Because these TOCTTOU (time of check to time of use) problems are avoided with the try except construct!

Answer (score 65):

You can access the environment variables using

```
import os
print os.environ
```

Try to see the content of the PYTHONPATH or PYTHONHOME environment variables. Maybe this will be helpful for your second question.

Answer (score 43):

As for the environment variables:

```
import os
print os.environ["HOME"]
```

Answer (score 36):

Import the `os` module:

```py
import os
```

To get an environment variable:

```py
os.environ.get('Env_var')
```

To set an environment variable:

```py
# Set environment variables
os.environ['Env_var'] = 'Some Value'
```

Answer (score 33):

```
import os
for a in os.environ:
    print('Var: ', a, 'Value: ', os.getenv(a))
print("all done")
```

That will print all of the environment variables along with their values.

Answer (score 26):

If you are planning to use the code in a production web application code, using any web framework like [Django](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29) and [Flask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flask_%28web_framework%29), use projects like [envparse](https://github.com/rconradharris/envparse). Using it, you can read the value as your defined type.

```
from envparse import env
# will read WHITE_LIST=hello,world,hi to white_list = ["hello", "world", "hi"]
white_list = env.list("WHITE_LIST", default=[])
# Perfect for reading boolean
DEBUG = env.bool("DEBUG", default=False)
```

NOTE: kennethreitz's [autoenv](https://github.com/kennethreitz/autoenv) is a recommended tool for making project-specific environment variables. For those who are using `autoenv`, please note to keep the `.env` file private (inaccessible to public).

Comment: [envparse](https://github.com/rconradharris/envparse) is used by about 4,000 people and has not been maintained since 2015, vs. [dotenv](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv), which is used by 240,000 people.  The people have spoken.

Answer (score 17):

There are also a number of great libraries. [Envs](https://pypi.org/project/envs/), for example, will allow you to parse objects out of your environment variables, which is rad. For example:

```
from envs import env
env('SECRET_KEY') # 'your_secret_key_here'
env('SERVER_NAMES',var_type='list') #['your', 'list', 'here']
```

Comment: What does "rad" mean in *"which is rad"*?  *[rad](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rad#Adjective)* - *"1. (slang) Clipping of radical; excellent"*

Answer (score 13):

**Edited - October 2021**

Following @Peter's comment, here's how you can test it:

`main.py`

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python


from os import environ

# Initialize variables
num_of_vars = 50
for i in range(1, num_of_vars):
    environ[f"_BENCHMARK_{i}"] = f"BENCHMARK VALUE {i}"  

def stopwatch(repeat=1, autorun=True):
    """
    Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68660080/5285732
    stopwatch decorator to calculate the total time of a function
    """
    import timeit
    import functools
    
    def outer_func(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def time_func(*args, **kwargs):
            t1 = timeit.default_timer()
            for _ in range(repeat):
                r = func(*args, **kwargs)
            t2 = timeit.default_timer()
            print(f"Function={func.__name__}, Time={t2 - t1}")
            return r
        
        if autorun:
            try:
                time_func()
            except TypeError:
                raise Exception(f"{time_func.__name__}: autorun only works with no parameters, you may want to use @stopwatch(autorun=False)") from None
        
        return time_func
    
    if callable(repeat):
        func = repeat
        repeat = 1
        return outer_func(func)
    
    return outer_func

@stopwatch(repeat=10000)
def using_environ():
    for item in environ:
        pass

@stopwatch
def using_dict(repeat=10000):
    env_vars_dict = dict(environ)
    for item in env_vars_dict:
        pass
```

```sh
python "main.py"

# Output
Function=using_environ, Time=0.216224731
Function=using_dict, Time=0.00014206099999999888
```

If this is true ... It's 1500x faster to use a `dict()` instead of accessing `environ` directly.

---

A performance-driven approach - calling `environ` is expensive, so it's better to call it once and save it to a dictionary. Full example:

```py
from os import environ


# Slower
print(environ["USER"], environ["NAME"])

# Faster
env_dict = dict(environ)
print(env_dict["USER"], env_dict["NAME"])
```

P.S- if you worry about exposing private environment variables, then sanitize `env_dict` after the assignment.

Comment: What do you mean sanitize? Like remove entries with sensitive data so maybe you don't accidentally throw api keys or secrets in app logs?

Comment: @ferreiradev yup, exactly that

Answer (score 11):

You can also try this:

First, install `python-decouple`

```
pip install python-decouple
```

Import it in your file

```
from decouple import config
```

Then get the environment variable

```
SECRET_KEY=config('SECRET_KEY')
```

Read more about the Python library [here](https://pypi.org/project/python-decouple/).

Answer (score 10):

You can use `python-dotenv` module to access environment variables

Install the module using:

```
pip install python-dotenv
```

After that, create a `.env` file that has the following entry:

```
BASE_URL = "my_base_url"
```

Then import the module into your Python file

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

# Load the environment variables
load_dotenv()

# Access the environment variable
print(os.getenv("BASE_URL"))
```

Comment: why would you install a third party library for something so simple?

Answer (score 7):

For Django, see [Django-environ](https://github.com/joke2k/django-environ).

```
$ pip install django-environ

import environ

env = environ.Env(
    # set casting, default value
    DEBUG=(bool, False)
)
# reading .env file
environ.Env.read_env()

# False if not in os.environ
DEBUG = env('DEBUG')

# Raises Django's ImproperlyConfigured exception if SECRET_KEY not in os.environ
SECRET_KEY = env('SECRET_KEY')
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. What is the context - in what context is the code executed? On a server with Django? Locally for testing it out? Somewhere else? What is the idea? What is the code supposed to accomplish?

Answer (score 4):

You should first import os using

```py
import os
```

and then actually print the environment variable value

```py
print(os.environ['yourvariable'])
```

of course, replace yourvariable as the variable you want to access.

Answer (score 3):

The tricky part of using nested *for-loops* in one-liners is that you **have** to use list comprehension. So in order to print **all** your environment variables, without having to import a foreign library, you can use:

```sh
python -c "import os;L=[f'{k}={v}' for k,v in os.environ.items()]; print('\n'.join(L))"
```

Answer (score 0):

With `os`:

```
import os

# get the value of the environment variable HOME
os.getenv('HOME')
os.environ['HOME']

# show all environment variables (like `set` in bash)
os.environ

# set environment variable MYVAR (note: it has to be a string)
os.environ["MYVAR"] = "x"

# unset variable MYVAR
del os.environ["MYVAR"]
```

For interactive work with IPython/Jupyter notebooks the magic [`%env`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-env) is also practical:

```
%env
%env HOME
%env MYVAR = "x"
# numbers are also allowed 
%env MYVAR = 3
```