# Python import from a different directory using "~" symbol

Tags: python

Under a linux structure, i've noticed that the following works:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/username/fullpathname/")
import my_module
```

however the following does not

```
import sys
sys.path.append("~/fullpathname")
import my_module
```

is there a way to use the "~" operator? I don't understand why python wants the full directory. Thank you!

Comment: `~` is expanded by the shell. Python needs a real path, whether relative or absolute.

Comment: See the accepted answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906977/python-environment-variables

Answer (score 7):

You can use `os.path.expanduser`:

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.expanduser("~/fullpathname"))
import mymodule
```

Comment: Worked great! Thanks! Any idea why this is not default behavior?

Comment: ~ only means 'home directory' on Unix systems. What if you were on Windows?

Comment: Just to add, even though ~user has no meaning to the Windows file system, `os.path.expanduser` should still work on Windows...