# How can I detect when a Django server is started without a settings module?

Tags: python, django

I want to `sys.exit()` the server when no settings module is defined.

As far as I'm aware a Django settings module can be passed in two ways:

1. By running the server using `--settings=app.settings.foo`
2. By setting an environment variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=app.settings.foo`.

How can I detect in my app when no settings module is defined, and where would be a good place to put this?

Comment: You mean when certain settings for your app aren't defined?

Comment: No, I mean when no settings *module* is defined when running the server, either via the settings parameter or the environment variable. — I could set some setting in my base settings file (which is imported by all other settings files), and in my app check if that setting exists, else: exit(), but that's a workaround that I want to use as a last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `manage.py` and `project/wsgi.py`:

Replace

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings")
```

With

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.exit")
```

Then create `project/exit.py` with contents:

```
import sys

print "No settings module specified."
sys.exit()
```

When you start the server without specifying `--settings` and without a `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable, it will print the message and exit.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this in your init.py

```
import os.path

#Check if file exists every time you use runserver
if not os.path.isfile(/path/of/your/settings.py):
    sys.exit()
```

But if you want avoid this approach you can [check if a enviroment variable exists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4907053/2010764). Also, if you want to raise an error when --settings it's not passed, you must [override the parameter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/).

Comment: Actually you [can](http://programming.oreilly.com/2014/04/simplifying-django.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't want to check if the settings file exists, I want to know if a non-default settings file was used. I found a simple way, see my answer.