# Using Python and Celery how to pass in an custom args

Tags: python, celery

I have a Celery task that I run locally using `celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info` or sometimes it runs on a live server.

```
@app.task
def example_task_calling_api():
      url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/" 
      #  url = "http://www.example.com/api/"
      content = requests.get(url)
      #Do something with content etc
```

At the moment I uncomment the url depending on what environment I'm running.

My question is, how can I pass into celery settings or extra args that I can use to setup the correct URL?

PS... I DON'T mean passing args to a task i.e. Task(123) but somesort of system wide variable set upon starting celery.

```
i.e. celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info -LOCALDEV
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to set the url as an environmental variable, and use python [`os.environ`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4907053/594589) to see if it is set and or set a default.

If you have multiple variables you'd like to config based on your env's: ie. demo, develop, production ect, you could use a python file and store all your varialbes in it.  Then when your application starts up you could select the correct settings file based on a command line argument or from an env variable.

The above suggestion is how django framework handles your issue.