# Get environment variable address with Python

Tags: python, c

for an university project I have to perform Buffer Overflow with some programs given by the professor.

I want to setup my shellcode environment variable with python and I do that with:

```
import os
os.environ("EGG") = "..."
os.system('bash')
```

so now python spawns a child bash process. But now how can I print the address of EGG?
I have done this with C:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("%x", getenv("EGG"));
    return 0;
}
```

but I want to do it with Python. Anyone can help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906977/how-to-access-environment-variables-from-python

Comment: What would you do with this address? Are you aware that each process has its own address space and its own copy of the environment?

Comment: @interjay: once I print the address, I can launch (remaining in the child bash process spawned by Python) the vulnerable program overwriting the return address with the one of my environment variable to execute the shellcode

Comment: Though shellcode is probably going to use some implementation specified or undefined behaviour anyway it might be pointless to point out that `printf("%x", getenv("EGG"))` is undefined behaviour: `"%x"` expects an `unsigned int` argument, but you gave it `char *`. The correct format specifier and call would be `printf("%p", (void *)getenv("EGG"))`.

Comment: @D.C. The address of the environment variable in the child bash process won't be the same as the address in the Python process.

Comment: @interjay at the end I have used gdb to get the address of my environment variable, without using Python or C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use id() https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id

```
id(os.environ.get('EGG')
```

in hex:

```
hex(id(os.environ.get('EGG'))
```

Comment: I have tried this but the C program and the Python one gives to me different results...

Comment: That would be the id (address in CPython) of the python string corresponding the env variable of the python process. A very different thing from the environment of the child process and a c-string.