# Get system environment variables on Windows in Python

Tags: python, windows, environment-variables

How can I get *system* environment variables on Windows? With the below code I *only* get the *user* environment variables:

```
os.environ['PATH']
```

Or this returns the same:

```
os.getenv('PATH')
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906977/how-to-access-environment-variables-from-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906977/how-to-access-environment-variables-from-python

Comment: You're limited to the environment variables restricted by your current user level. Meaning you need to run as administrator go get certain paths, some paths are only local to the user.

Comment: Dear [iHowell](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1137713/ihowell), at your link I do not find the answer.

Comment: Dear [Torxed](http://stackoverflow.com/users/929999/torxed), I think your comment could be the answer :(

Answer (score 3):

Based on a (deleted) comment I found the solution. System environment variables should be read from the registry if the Python script is run by a user and not by administrator.

```
import winreg

reg_path = r'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment'

reg_key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, reg_path)

system_environment_variables = winreg.QueryValueEx(reg_key, 'Path')[0]
```

Comment: It is not true that `os.environ['PATH']` only returns the user `PATH`. When you log on with a loaded profile, your user `PATH` is appended to the system `PATH`, which is inherited by Explorer and all of its child processes.

Comment: I run the `os.environ['PATH']` on my Win7 x64 with my user, and I got only the user environment variables. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but my user PATH has only 3 variables, and my system PATH has more than 30, and python returns only with the 3. In python I was not able to run external commands via `subprocess` because python does not see the system PATH. So I had to read the registry for the system PATH and set this explicitly at `subprocess.Popen()`. So now I can run my commands.

Comment: Which variables do you get? Are they the same as the user variables in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment`? If cmd.exe is run with an empty environment, it sets 3 default variables: `COMSPEC`, `PATHEXT`, and `PROMPT`. The default values have nothing to do with the user's environment variables.

Comment: Yes, with `os.environ['PATH']` I get the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment`. If I open cmd.exe in Windows then I can use every executable regarding to system PATH (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment`)

Comment: Running python.exe as a child of cmd.exe should inherit the *exact same* `PATH` value that you see in cmd.exe via `set PATH`.

Comment: Yes, it works! Thank you! Before, I tested my python script using Spyder

Comment: Spyder probably has a setting to customize the environment variables that it passes to the interpreter.