# Handling Secret Keys when deploying Flask app on AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, secret-key

Working on deploying a Flask application using AWS, but the Flask app relies on API secret keys that I have saved in a config.ini file on my computer. Should I be uploading that file with the keys to AWS? How should my Flask app access those keys once deployed to AWS?

Comment: How are you deploying on AWS? On EC2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can possibly do one of the following (Assuming that you're deploying on a Linux Based OS):

1. Store the keys in variables and then export them from the file: `~/.bash_profile`
2. Save them as environment variables

   You can checkout this answer to see how to access them : [Access environment variables from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4906977/1542307)

Answer (score 2):

I have not used Flask yet but as a good practice for deployment, you should never save your API keys/credentials in plain text anywhere.

For AWS related deployments which require API keys, I would suggest you use the [IAM instance roles](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html) which have the required access that your application needs.