# Build the name of Bamboo variable in script

Tags: shell, bamboo

Is it possible to concatenate a string to call a Bamboo variable.

Using a script task in Bamboo, I want to generalize the following:

```
python my.py moon ${bamboo.mynamespace.moon}
```

to

```
SET planet=MOON
python my.py %planet% ${bamboo.mynamespace.%planet%}
```

But doing it like the second example above results in my python script receiving

```
${bamboo.mynamespace.%planet%}
```

as a string and not the value of

```
${bamboo.mynamespace.moon}
```

I know... moon is not a planet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's going to be possible in the way how you're using it. Because once you use `${bamboo.variableName}` Bamboo tries to resolve the variable and substitute it with a variable value. Since there's no `variable%planet%` Bamboo can't reference it.

**But** I think you could reorganise your solution a bit and make use environment variables (all Bamboo variables are passed to process as environment variables). So e.g. if Bamboo variable's name is *variable.name* you're allowed to reference to it via *${bamboo_variable_name}* (bamboo prefix + all dots are replaced with underscore)

Then I can imagine you could get variable which interests you via `print os.environ['bamboo_mynamespace_' + 'planet']` (more info on env variables in python [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4907053/769187))

Comment: Aha.. Clever. I'll try it

Comment: Excellent, it works. Cant get how I missed that, since the bamboo log prints out all variables it injects to OS ENV. *BUT* the underscore instead of dots isn't obvious at all! Thanks.

Comment: "bamboo log prints out all variables it injects to OS ENV" ? No it doesn't. hehe...