# Export a variable from bash and use it in Python

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I am trying to write a script which is executing couple of things on a Linux server and I would like to use bash for most of the Linux specific commands and only use Python for the most complex stuff, but in order to do that I will need to export some variables from the bash script and use them in the python script and I didn't find a way how I can do that. So I have tried to create two very little scripts to test this functionality: 
1.sh is a bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

test_var="Test Variable"
export test_var
echo "1.sh has been executed"
python 2.sh
```

2.sh is a Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

print("The python script has been invoked successfully")
print(test_var)
```

As you can guess when I execute the first script the second fails with the error about unknown variable:

```
$ ./1.sh
1.sh has been executed
The python script has been invoked successfully
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "2.sh", line 4, in <module>
    print(test_var)
NameError: name 'test_var' is not defined
```

The reason why I am trying to do that is because I am more comfortable with bash and I want to use $1, $2 variables in bash. Is this also possible in Python?

[EDIT] - I have just found out how I can use $1 and $2 it in Python. You need to use `sys.argv[1]` and `sys.argv[2]` and import the sys module `import sys`

Comment: Why not just use `os.environ['test_var']` if you wan't to access environment variables?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906977/how-do-i-access-environment-variables-from-python

Comment: You also could pass variable to Python scripts: `python 1.py "variable-value"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To use environment variables from your python script you need to call:

```
import os
os.environ['test_var']
```

`os.environ` is a dictionary with all the environment variables, you can use all the method a dict has. For instance, you could write :

```
os.environ.get('test_var', 'default_value')
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but I think you can easily omit the `, 'default_value'` part. It works just fine with `os.environ.get('test_var')`

Comment: It will also work if you use a simple dict lookup `os.environ['test_var']`. Use the `get` method with a default only when it make sense - when the value will not always exist in the environment variable.

Answer (score 7):

Check python extension it should be .py instead of .sh 
1.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
 test_var="Test Variable"
 export test_var
 echo "1.sh has been executed"
 python 2.py
```

os library will gave you the access the environment variable. Following python code will gave you the required result,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
print("The python script has been invoked successfully")
print(os.environ['test_var'])
```

Check for reference : [How do I access environment variables from Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906977/how-do-i-access-environment-variables-from-python)

Comment: I think here you need to put `.get` in your print statement, without it it doesn't work: `print(os.environ.get['test_var'])`

Comment: @GeorgеStoyanov I have executed above code on ubuntu and It worked without .get.

Comment: if I execute it without the `.get` I get an error: `AttributeError: _Environ instance has no __call__ method`. I am also using Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS.

Comment: If i execute with .get ,  get an error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "2.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(os.environ.get['test_var']) 
TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

Comment: That's really strange. Here it works only if I add `.get` trailing.

Comment: ohh i got the mistake .get is the method so os.environ.get('test_var') works on my end and there is also alternative  os.environ['test_var']