# I trained my model on google datalab but I can't run it on my local machine

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-datalab

I trained my model on google datalab and then exported my model to make predictions on a seperate machine. When I load the model in datalab it works perfectly, but When I load the model on my local machine, I get weird errors such as:

> Segmentation 11

my assumption is that my environment variables are different in both environments. How can I match both environments so that they have the same environment variables. Any guidance will be very appreciated

this is the code I use to load my model

```
from keras.models import load_model 
model = load_model('new_model.h5')
```

Comment: can you post full error message?

Comment: This is impossible to diagnose without a full error message. Also, what versions of things are you using in datalab and locally?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you mean Python related environment variables.
Maybe you might [check this manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906977/how-do-i-access-environment-variables-from-python) to compare which are the differences.