# How to access environment variables inside container at runtime ?

Tags: python, kubernetes

We aware of that we can define environment variables in pod/containers. i wanted to use the same environment variable inside the container at runtime.

ex: i am running a webapplication using python ,  inside that how to i get the values of environment values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I access environment variables from Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906977/how-do-i-access-environment-variables-from-python)

Comment: This isn't a Kubernetes/docker specific problem

Comment: i have created docker image and installed it in kubernetes. at runtime of my application i am unable to get env variable

Comment: Well, perhaps you should show your code and service definition. Otherwise, linked question and given answers all work fine inside containers, or not

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/69934
can you please look into the issue.

Answer (score 3):

First go inside the pod or `exec` the `bash`(`kubeclt exec -it <pod_name> bash`) and run `printenv` to get some idea what are the environmental variables available.

From Python

```
import os
os.environ['MYCUSTOMVAR']
```

Comment: printenv is working fine. but if i want to access from the pod it is not showing the env variables. it shows the env variables that are defined in circus. 
i want to access env variables used in deployment.yaml files

Comment: @Nanthakumar Not sure what you are trying to achieve. I believe your python script is inside of pod?? You can access all environmental(Including environmental variables that you defined in yaml)

Comment: I can confirm the same problem. All the environment vairiables exist but the os.environ[] returns KeyError

Answer (score 0):

Accessing environment variables is pretty easy with the `os` module.

```
import os
os.environ.get("ENV_VAR_NAME")
```