# SMTPSenderRefused at /password-reset/ error

Tags: python, django

How can I solve this problem?

> EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('mymail@gmail.com')
>
> EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('generatedpassword')

I have generated google app password and put both email and pass on the correct field, still I got this error. Is there any steps to follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you actually have environment variables set for `EMAIL_HOST_USER` and `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD`? `os.environ.get` takes a key corresponding to a system environment variable as the argument, and will return `None` by default if an environment variable matching that key cannot be found.

What is happening right now is it's looking for an environment variable called `mymail@gmail.com`, and because that likely does not exist, it returns `None` and causes the error you're experiencing.

You should set up an environment variable `EMAIL_HOST_USER` with a **value** of `mymail@gmail.com`, and another with the key being `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD` with value `generatedpassword` for what you are doing to work.

Note that you can call them something else if you prefer, the name does not have to match the Django settings variable.

See [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906977/how-to-access-environment-variable-values) for more information on using `os.environ.get()`.