# How do I call environment variables outside of settings.py?

Tags: python

I'm using [python-dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv) to set up environment variables and I got everything to work. I can now call my environment variables from `settings.py` that I defined in `.env`. That's cool and all but is there a way to call the environment variables from other files in subdirectories? Note that I'm not using django or any framework.

```
# settings.py

import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
BASEDIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
load_dotenv(os.path.join(BASEDIR, '.env'))

CLIENT_ID = os.getenv("CLIENT_ID")

# This works!
print(CLIENT_ID)
```

```
# other_file.py

import os

CLIENT_ID = os.getenv("CLIENT_ID")

# This does not :(, prints None
print(CLIENT_ID)
```

I'm sure I can load `.env` in every file where env variables are needed, but is there a more efficient way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906977/how-to-access-environment-variable-values?rq=1

Comment: @cricket_007 `os.getenv` only works in `settings.py`. I'm assuming it's because I loaded the `.env` file there. Is it best practice to load `.env` every time I need to call an environment variable or is there a better way?

Comment: It should work in your entire program after the settings file is loaded... Why can't you import settings from other scripts?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to know the path of the `.env` file relative to the subdirectory, import dotenv and `load_dotenv({path})`. For example, if your `.env` is in `/`, and `other_file.py` is in `/subdir1/subdir2/` (`/subdir1/subdir2/other_file.py`), then you would have to

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv('../../.env')
```