# is there any way to login zabbix API without giving Username ans password in script

Tags: zabbix

I am using pyzabbix module to use the Zabbix API, but is there any way to login the Zabbix API without giving the username and password in Python script?
Like any API token which serves the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

There are no API tokens or similar access methods in Zabbix currently.

Answer (score 0):

There is not, but you should use an environment variable (see [environment variable in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906977/how-to-access-environment-variable-values)) to store the password/token anyway, in order to avoid having it inside the code in cleartext. The environment is visible to the user only, and is usually initialized from a protected file (0600 permission in unix style), or a masked CI/CD variable.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Zabbix 5.4.7
There is a section API tokens under:

Administration -> General -> API tokens

Comment: I then put it on the auth value in the json request

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).