# Shell command excution on Python2.7

Tags: python-2.7, shell, subprocess

Want to verify if site domain contains "com". Assume I have shell varibale as

```
export FIRST_URL="http://www.11111.com" 
export SECOND_URL="http://www.22222.org"
```

User calls Python script with parameter (partial shell varibale) as

```
python2.7  FIRST     # OR
python2.7  SECOND
```

Python script is,

```
import sys, os, subprocess

PART_URL = sys.argv[1]
print( "PART_URL=",PART_URL)

COMPLETE_URL = PART_URL+'_URL'       # Formed a full shell varibale
cmd_str='echo {} | grep \"com\".format(COMPLETE_URL)'  # equivalent to echo $FIRST_URL | grep com

my_site=subprocess.check_output(cmd_str, shell=True)   # Note we cant use subprocess.run() in Python Python 2.7
print("The validated Site is ", my_site)
```

The output should be "The validated Site is http://www.11111.com"

Comment: Why don't you just pass the URL itself as the argument? And why are you shelling out to `grep` to check the format rather than doing the validation in the script itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out,

```
COMPLETE_URL = PART_URL+'_URL'     
cmd_str='echo ${} | grep \'com\'.format(COMPLETE_URL)' 
my_site=subprocess.check_output(cmd_str, shell=True)
```

Alteratively, we can use,

```
my_site=subprocess.call(shlex.split(cmd_str))
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer [How to access environment variable values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906977/how-to-access-environment-variable-values)

```
$ export FIRST_VAR="http://www.11111.com"
$ python
>>> foo = 'FIRST'
>>> print os.environ[foo + '_VAR']
http://www.11111.com
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding but you haven't read completely the query, 1) One part is forming the dynamic environment string, 2) second part is get the value for that created environment.

Comment: I did read it :) May be I should have added more clarification.

1. Dynamic variable name: I haven't posted the full code snippet above. I've hardcoded `foo` to the value `FIRST` but that's something you can read from sys.argv[1], add a pre-defined suffix (in this case `_VAR`) and get the full variable name.
2. Retrieving the value: os.environ[foo + '_VAR'] will get the value for that created environment variable.

Comment: Thanks, i wanted to see the code line with subprocess.check_output(cmd_str, shell=True) , what is cmd_str? could you post that please?

Comment: os.environ directly gives you access to the value of the environment variables. Why do you want to launch another process, run echo and get the output when there's a much simpler way to do it?

Comment: I edited script as above to validate the site if contains 'com' in it. Could you see it please.

Comment: First export those 2 varibles with values, they run python script as "python2.7 test.py FISRT" or "python2.7 test.py SECOND"

Comment: The domain may contain more than 1 period. foo.bar.bat or foo.bar.bat.co - I think the domain detection logic could/should be more generic to handle more than just .com. Also, regular expressions (python module re) would be a much better choice than using grep to detect and filter out substrings.

Please note StackOverflow is a forum to get a resolution to queries and not to get readymade answers. I'd recommend reading on the `os` and `re` modules and taking a python tutorial to code your logic in a more efficient way (rather than force-fitting shell constructs in a python script).