# Need to replace similar key values in a config file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to replace values in a config file given below with some values that i will be getting from env variables . Below is the config file

```
vnv:
{
 endpoints: {
        directflow: {
            host = "http://xxxx.xxx.xyz.xxx.com/ver0.1/call/in.xml.gz";
        };
        incidents: {
            host = "http://xxxx.xxx.xyz.xxx.com/ver0.1/call/in.xml.gz";

        };
    };
    sleep = 30;
    timeout = 30;
};
```

i need to replace the host with values from environment variable. This file is not a json file. What approach should i take to substitute values here.

Comment: Why not use a regex? http://www.noah.org/wiki/RegEx_Python#URL_regex_pattern

Comment: What have you tried ? Can you parse the file to handle it in Python or can you just use the text content ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906977/how-to-access-environment-variable-values?rq=1

Comment: CONFIG_FILE='file.cfg'


with open(CONFIG_FILE, 'r') as file:
    filedata = file.read()

Comment: i will get the env variables using os module but how do i replace env value in my cfg file is the question i have

Comment: you want to replace only the `xxxx.xxx.xyz.xxx` part ?

Comment: yes host = "<this part with the env variables that i wil get from os.environ>"

Comment: check my answer

Comment: need to replace both the host entries with env1 and env2 . for example directflow: {
            host = "env1" and incidents: {
            host = "env2";

        };

Answer (score 2):

you can use `os.environ`:

```
import os

host = os.environ.get('MY_ENV_HOST')
```

---

to replace in your file you can use:

```
import os
import re

with open('file.cfg') as fp:
    text = fp.read()

env_host = os.environ.get('MY_ENV_HOST')

host = f'http://{env_host}.com/'

new_text = re.sub(r'http://.*\.com/', host, text)

with open('file.cfg', 'w') as fp:
    fp.write(new_text)
```

Comment: Really need an answer for that ? There is dozen of duplicates ;)

Comment: I just want to show an example, there are many ways and libraries to achieve this