# how can I create nested dictionary keys and assign them values from a list of namespaced key value pairs?

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, key-value

I have env vars that looks like this:

```
CONFIG-SOMEKEY-SOMEOTHERKEY = val345
CONFIG-SOMEKEY-SOMEOTHEROTHERKEY = val678
CONFIG-ANOTHERKEY = val222
```

I want to create a dictionary out of them that would look like:

```
{
  'SOMEKEY': {
    'SOMEOTHERKEY': 'val3242',
    'SOMEOTHEROTHERKEY': 'val678'
  }
  'ANOTHERKEY': 'val222'
}
```

"CONFIG-" is a prefix to denote which vars this should be done with- so I can filter them easily like this:

```
config_fields = [i for i in os.environ if i.startswith("CONFIG-")]
```

But I'm unsure of how to loop over the string, split on "-" and build a dict.

While looping I was thinking I could check if its the last item and assign the value but how would it know the full path of keys it's on?

I suspect this is a job for recursion I'm just now sure exactly how to implement it

Comment: thanks, that was a typo, fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
data = ['CONFIG-SOMEKEY-SOMEOTHERKEY = val345',
        'CONFIG-SOMEKEY-SOMEOTHEROTHERKEY = val678',
        'CONFIG-ANOTHERKEY = val222']

result = {}
for e in data:
    key, value = e.split(" = ")  # split into key and value
    path = key.split("-")  # split the key into parts
    ref = result
    for part in path[1:-1]:
        ref[part] = part in ref and ref[part] or {}
        ref = ref[part]
    ref[path[-1]] = value  # take the last part of key and set the value

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{'SOMEKEY': {'SOMEOTHERKEY': 'val345', 'SOMEOTHEROTHERKEY': 'val678'}, 'ANOTHERKEY': 'val222'}
```

This part:

```
ref = result
for part in path[1:-1]:
    ref[part] = part in ref and ref[part] or {}
    ref = ref[part]
ref[path[-1]] = value
```

will create the nested dictionaries, is equivalent to:

```
for part in path[1:-1]:
    if part not in ref:
        ref[part] = {}
    ref = ref[part]
```

So if the `part` is in the dictionary you set ref as the value corresponding to `part` otherwise you create a new dictionary.

Comment: `CONFIG-SOMEKEY-SOMEOTHERKEY = val345` isnt a string though the value of the CONFIG-SOMEKEY-SOMEOTHERKEY env var is val345

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your point? How is this different from the output required in your question?

Comment: You could use `setdefault()` here?

Comment: @NomadMonad I could but each call to setdefault will create a dictionary object, this way the expression is shortcircuited and does not create unnecesary objects.

Comment: Could you step through the snippet that creates the nested dict in your answer a little more? Im still trying to fully understand how it works

Comment: @red888 Updated the answer

Comment: @DaniMesejo dont mean to sound pedantic but `for part in path[1:-1]:
        ref = ref.setdefault(part, dict())` would save you one line. Good answer though, you got my upvote.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `assoc_in` function from [toolz](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.dicttoolz.assoc_in). Split the name on `-` and slice off the prefix.

```
import os

from toolz.dictoolz import assoc_in

CONFIG={}

for k, v in os.environ.items():
    if k.startswith("CONFIG-"):
        assoc_in(CONFIG, k.split('-')[1:], v)
```

---

If you don't want to add a dependency, you can see the implementation of `assoc_in` [here](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.dicttoolz.assoc_in). A simpler substitute might be something like

```
def assoc_in(d, ks, v):
    for k in ks[:-1]:
        d = d.setdefault(k, {})
    d[ks[-1]] = v
```

This uses the `.setdefault()` method to get the nested dicts, which will add a new one if it doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can get your environment variables like so:

```
import os

text = [f"{k} = {v}" for k,v in os.environ.items() if k.startswith("CONFIG-")]
print(env)
```

(inspired by [How to access environment variable values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906977/how-to-access-environment-variable-values) - especially this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4907002/7505395))

Then you can use dicts to iterativly splitting your values:

```
text = """CONFIG-SOMEKEY-SOMEOTHERKEY = val345
CONFIG-SOMEKEY-SOMEOTHEROTHERKEY = val678
CONFIG-ANOTHERKEY = val222"""

text = text.split("\n")

d = {}

curr_d = d
for part in text:
    while "-" in part:
        a, b = part.split("-",1)
        if '-' in b:
            curr_d [a] = curr_d.get(a,{})
            curr_d = curr_d[a]
        part = b
    a, b = part.split("=",1)
    curr_d[a] = b

    curr_d = d

print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'CONFIG': {'SOMEOTHERKEY ': ' val345', 
            'SOMEOTHEROTHERKEY ': ' val678'}, 
 'ANOTHERKEY ': ' val222'}
```