# How to use environment variables in Python in Glitch

Tags: python, environment-variables, glitch-framework

I am working on a Python API project on the Glitch platform and I didn't find anything on how to reference the .env file and use the variables in a python script. `os.environ` will not work because I haven't imported anything to the app. How should I reference it properly and how should I import the module correctly?

```
import os
var = os.environ['SECRET_NAME']  # Will raise a KeyError if not existed
var2 = os.environ.get('SECRET_NAME')  # Will give a value of 'None" if not existed
```

Comment: process.env is how you access env vars in *JavaScript*. If you're asking how to access env vars in Python, have you tried researching that?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, I searched everywhere on how to refrence .env in a python script

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906977/how-to-access-environment-variable-values? https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/?

Answer (score 0):

Use code below to access environment variables from .env file.

[python-dotenv documentation](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/)

```
import os
from os.path import join, dirname
from dotenv import load_dotenv

dotenv_path = join(dirname(__file__), '.env')
load_dotenv(dotenv_path)

SECRET_NAME = os.environ.get("SECRET_NAME")
```