# How to access secret variable within the python script

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipeline-python-script-task

I have a simple script to read the secret variable set in the azure-pipeline.
I am able to print from "script" step directly, but not able to resolve in the python script.
When I print inline, it works.
This seems like a very basic thing, but I have checked quite a few blogs and options.
This blog seemed to talk about the issue I am facing: https://brandonsnotepad.wordpress.com/2021/04/23/azure-devops-secret-variables-python/
But didn't help :(
I haven't got it working so far.

Working:

```
steps:
- script: echo $TOKEN
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'
  env:
    TOKEN: $(TOKEN)
```

Output: xxx

Above output is understandable.

I want to have this token within my script for further processing

```
- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'filePath'
    scriptPath: './test.py'
    failOnStderr: true
  env:
   TOKEN: $(TOKEN)
  displayName: 'Get Token'
```

test.py
I tried below options:
1.

```
token = os.getenv("TOKEN")
```

In this case, I got this error. I am using 3.7.10 python version

```
NameError: name 'os' is not defined
```

So I tried to do `pip install os`, but ended with this error. My understanding is `os` is a default package that should come with python. But still tried based on the above error.

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement os (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for os
```

2. Then I tried to refer the way I did in one-line script.

```
token = $(TOKEN)
```

Error:
`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

3. Then assuming, since it is a variable and passed from the script, I tried this as well

```
token = TOKEN
```

Error:
`NameError: name 'TOKEN' is not defined`

Comment: Your script is missing `import os`?

Comment: This has more to do with python than pipelines. See [How to access environment variable values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906977/how-to-access-environment-variable-values).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set environment variables in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971312/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-python)

Comment: @swetha-setty were you able to resolve this secrets usage in python script from devops env injection?