# How to list out all the environment variable in python?

Tags: python, environment

I want to list out all the environment variables in my system in python. The list should give me the name of the variable and its value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I access environment variables in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906977/how-do-i-access-environment-variables-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

Using os module of python it is possible to list out the environment variables.

```
import os

for name, value in os.environ.items():
    print("{0}: {1}".format(name, value))
```