# Dynamically get/set dockerfile variables

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, environment-variables

I'm trying to create dockerfile similar to the following one:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
ENV FOO=bar
RUN python my_python_file.py  # use the FOO variable, and set PY_VERSION variable

FROM python:<PY_VERSION>-slim-buster
# continue dockerfile...
```

1. How can I use the FOO variable from within my python `my_python_file` script?
   (I think I can pass `FOO` as an argument to the `RUN python my_python_file.py` command, and read the argument from within the `my_python_file.py` file. I wonder if there's an easier way, something that maybe using `os.getenv('FOO')`)
2. How can I set `PY_VERSION` from within my python `my_python_file` script, to later be used by the 2nd `FROM` command - `FROM python:<PY_VERSION>-slim-buster`?

I dont have any control over how the `docker build` command is being executed.

Comment: for 1. you can do just that, however I would use ARG instead of ENV. for 2. it cannot be done. that's a logic that is better implemented outside Dockerfile

Comment: Thanks @Mihai.
Regarding 2.
why it's not possible? I guess it's because there is no way for a python script to set a dockerfile ENV / ARG variables at `build` runtime?

Comment: because docker was not built for such a workflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I use the FOO variable from within my python my_python_file script?

Read it from environment variables.

> omething that maybe using os.getenv('FOO'))

[How do I access environment variables in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906977/how-do-i-access-environment-variables-in-python)

> How can I set PY_VERSION from within my python my_python_file script, to later be used by the 2nd FROM command - FROM python:<PY_VERSION>-slim-buster?

That is not possible.

> Dynamically get/set dockerfile variables

Generate the Dockerfile file from a wrapper script.