# Use environment variable as connection with paramiko (Python)

Tags: python, variables, ssh, environment, paramiko

How can I use environment variable to connect with paramiko package.
My parameters currently are hard coded:
client.connect(hostname="",username="",password="")

Comment: Answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4907053/3268228

Comment: Not exactly, I need to use it in paramiko client.connect function and not sure how