# Shell out from ruby while setting an environment variable

Tags: ruby, shell, environment

I need to shell out to a process while setting an environment variable for it. I tried this one-liner:

```
system "RBENV_VERSION=system ruby extconf.rb"
```

<del>This syntax works in shell script but not from ruby.</del> (**Update:** turns out this syntax works from ruby after all, but I failed to see its effect due to my particular use-case.)

So I'm doing this:

```
rbenv_version = ENV['RBENV_VERSION']
ENV['RBENV_VERSION'] = 'system'
begin
  system "ruby extconf.rb"
ensure
  ENV['RBENV_VERSION'] = rbenv_version
end
```

I'm forced to such a long expression because I don't want to override the environment variable permanently if it already had a value.

Anything shorter that comes to your mind?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

```
system({"MYVAR" => "42"}, "echo $MYVAR")
```

`system` accepts any arguments that `Process.spawn` accepts.

Comment: This is a great answer. The documentation for [`Kernel#system`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-system) is not sufficiently clear on this functionality. Very nice.

Comment: For ruby 1.8, look at @rtomayko's POSIX::Spawn, linked in another comment.

Comment: I am getting `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Hash into String` ...?

Comment: @Avdi do you know if there is a way to append a value at the end of the environment variable instead of replacing it? Something like: `system({"INCLUDE" => "C:\Qt;%INCLUDE%",  "echo %INCLUDE%"})`

Answer (score 7):

Ruby 1.9 includes [`Process::spawn`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Process.html#method-c-spawn) which allows an environ hash to be provided.

`Process::spawn` is also the foundation for `system`, `exec`, `popen`, etc.
You can pass an environment to each.

Under Ruby 1.8, you may want to consider the [`POSIX::Spawn`](https://github.com/rtomayko/posix-spawn) library,
which provides the same interfaces

Comment: Good to know! But the invocation is kinda clunky: `Process.wait Process.spawn({"MYVAR" => "42"}, "echo $MYVAR")` for my simple needs. Turns out the `system` func also supports this optional hash argument!

Comment: `system` accepts all arguments that `Process.spawn()` accepts. See my answer for example.

Answer (score 4):

Using your same approach, but wrapped up as a block method that temporarily modifies the environment (like the block form of `Dir.chdir`):

```
def with_environment(variables={})
  if block_given?
    old_values = variables.map{ |k,v| [k,ENV[k]] }
    begin
       variables.each{ |k,v| ENV[k] = v }
       result = yield
    ensure
      old_values.each{ |k,v| ENV[k] = v }
    end
    result
  else
    variables.each{ |k,v| ENV[k] = v }
  end
end

with_environment 'RBENV_VERSION'=>'system' do
  `ruby extconf.rb`
end
```

Comment: I use such approach often in tests, but here it's an overkill.

Comment: @AnonymousDownvoter I encourage you to downvote answers that are _wrong_, and upvote answers that are _better_ than others. Downvoting one (correct) answer presumably because there are other answers that are better (easier, shorter) is not in the spirit of Stack Overflow, IMHO.

Comment: +1  first, for getting an unfair downvote.  2nd, because this is my favorite answer.  I was more excited until I realized you had defined :with_environment.  It's sad, because that's the method that should exist in Ruby itself.

Answer (score 3):

Actually that worked for me.

```
shai@comp ~ » irb                                                                                                                                     
1.9.3p0 :001 > system %{SHAIGUITAR=exists ruby -e 'puts ENV["SHAIGUITAR"]'}
exists
 => true
```

But if it doesn't, maybe you can try prepending "env" to whatever variable you need. E.g.

```
system(%{env SHAIGUITAR=exists ruby bla.rb})
```

Comment: It works for me too. I'm an idiot, I tried it and discarded it after I didn't get the desired effect, but it was because of my particular use-case and not because this isn't supported. Thanks!

Comment: The only thing that doesn't work with this – and this is very weird – is the "echo" example. That's why I'm marking the other answer as correct – it covers more cases.

Answer (score 2):

This may work?

```
system <<-CMD
export VARNAME=123
other_command
CMD
```

Comment: That works. One line: `system 'export VARNAME=123 && other_command'`