# Right way to pass environment variables to exec shell command

Tags: ruby

I'm using ruby 1.8.7 patch 249. Is the following the best/only way to pass environment variables to a shell command that I need to execute from my ruby program?

```
fork do       
   ENV['A'] = 'A'
   exec "/bin/bash -c 'echo $A'"
end

Process.wait
```

Comment: Same for `system`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301294/shell-out-from-ruby-while-setting-an-environment-variable

Answer (score 43):

There is a really easy way:

```
system({"MYVAR" => "42"}, "echo $MYVAR")
```

All credit for this goes to Avdi: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8301399/171933

Comment: It is worth noting that `popen3` has the same behaviour with control over stdin,stdout,stderr see [https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen3](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen3)

Comment: I am seeing "TypeError: no implicit conversion of Hash into String".

Comment: @AndyHayden Are all the values in your hash strings? Could you post your code?

Comment: Code was `system({ "DENO_BUILD_MODE" => "release" }, "python", "tools/test.py")`, it was for [homebrew-core](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/35645/commits/f842d1d31caf59975295662da45c9c1a1776b457). I wonder if they override `system`?

Comment: @AndyHayden Hmmm.... maybe they do... I haven't been working with Ruby for a while, but you might want to try `spawn` instead of `system`, it has the same syntax. I just tried both `system` and `spawn` on my Mac with Ruby 2.3.7 and it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

For 1.8~ users - replicates 1.9 behaviour of exec. Same as OP's initial attempt though.

```
def exec_env(hash, cmd)
  hash.each do |key,val|
    ENV[key] = val
  end
  exec cmd
end

exec_env({"A"=>"A"}, "/bin/bash -c 'echo $A'")
```

Comment: This works for `exec` since `exec` never returns, but note that it's different for `system`, which has the same signature - environment variables set via `system(env_hash, command)` are set for the command, but not left in Ruby's `ENV` when the command completes.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in one line

```
exec "/bin/bash -c 'A=hello; echo $A'"
```

Comment: I like my way better because then you don't have to worry about escaping semicolons, single quotes, and anything else that bash would interpret in a special way.

Comment: This is the right answer for older versions of Ruby (like the version mentioned by the OP).