# Installing and starting daemon script via Capistrano 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano3

I've been trying this for days without success now. I am using Capistrano 3 to deploy my Ruby on Rails 4 code on my production server.

At the end of the deployment process, I want to restart my daemon scripts, which I would manually do by this command:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec ruby script/my_daemon restart
```

On my Capistrano 3 recipe (`config/deploy.rb`) I've tried a few different settings but none of those worked.

```
namespace :deploy do
  desc 'Restart application'

  task :restart do
invoke 'unicorn:restart'
  end
  after :publishing, :restart

  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do

      within release_path do
        execute :rake, 'tmp:cache:clear'

        # Daemons
        # This ends up with an error
        execute :bundle, :exec, :ruby, "RAILS_ENV=production /var/www/MY_APP/current/script/my_daemon restart;"

        # This starts the daemon, but in development environment
        execute :bundle, :exec, :ruby, "/var/www/MY_APP/current/script/my_daemon restart RAILS_ENV=production;"

        # This also starts the daemon, but in development environment
        execute :bundle, :exec, :ruby, "/var/www/MY_APP/current/script/my_daemon restart;"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Could someone help me write the right recipe to restart my daemons in production environment? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shell out from ruby while setting an environment variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301294/shell-out-from-ruby-while-setting-an-environment-variable)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch it is not duplicate of that question because here command will be executed on remote system via sshkit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting env via capistrano dsl

```
within release_path do
  with rails_env: :production do
    execute :bundle, :exec, :ruby, "#{current_path}/script/my_daemon restart"
  end
end
```