# Ruby: pass environment variable to sudo script?

Tags: ruby, shell, environment-variables, environment

I have a follow-up question regarding [Shell out from ruby while setting an environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301294/shell-out-from-ruby-while-setting-an-environment-variable/8301399#8301399). I try to feed the environment variable to a shell script via sudo, but not successful.

This is the sample one-line script, "/usr/bin/wrapper.sh".

```
echo $MYVAR
```

Test,

```
$ irb
> system({'MYVAR' => "42"}, "echo $MYVAR")        ==> GOOD
> system({'MYVAR' => "42"}, "wrapper.sh")         ==> GOOD
> system({'MYVAR' => "42"}, "sudo echo $MYVAR")   ==> GOOD
> system({'MYVAR' => "42"}, "sudo wrapper.sh")    ==> NOT GOOD
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a way to flag that variable as `export` so it affects subshells. `wrapper.sh` is not running in the same process as `sudo`'s immediate shell. Does `ENV['MYVAR'] = 42` before running it propagate properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need sudo -E

```
$ irb
>> system({'MYVAR' => "42"}, "sudo wrapper.sh")
=> true
>> system({'MYVAR' => "42"}, "wrapper.sh")
42
=> true
>> system({'MYVAR' => "42"}, "sudo -E wrapper.sh")
42
=> true
>>
```